# Retrofit error message is broken

Tags: android, json, retrofit

onResponse is called.
But response.isSuccessful() is false.

I want to watch error massage.

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UserInfo> call, Response<UserInfo> response) {

            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                try {
                   Log.d("Success false", response.errorBody().string()); // letter broken!!
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return;
            }
}
```

print :

```
{"error":"\ub85c\uadf8\uc778\uc774 \ud544\uc694\ud569\ub2c8\ub2e4."}
```

Why letter is broken?

Comment: U have not Implemented properly try to see this http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html

Comment: I see only github document. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it!

I think of json data as a string data.
error massage is json data.
json data need convert.

Try this :

```
JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject ( response.errorBody().string());
Log.d("error",jsonobject.getString("error");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is UTF8 encoded string. You could decode it by URLDecoder.decode(s, s)